# BLOB to XMLType XML parsing failed in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, xmltype, character-set

I can't convert BLOB to XMLType in oracle database.
I've tried this:

```
select
XMLType( BLOB_COLUMN,
         1 /* this is character set ID. 1 == USASCII | ISO-8859-2 char ID?*/
       ) as XML
from my_table;
```

I got this error message:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00200: could not convert from encoding US-ASCII to ISO-8859-2
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 265
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

My question is, how to convert this BLOB (ISO-8859-2) to XMLType?
What is the character ID of ISO-8859-2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nls_charset_id](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions095.htm) to get ID:

```
select
XMLType( BLOB_COLUMN,
         nls_charset_id('ISO-8859-2')
       ) as XML
from my_table;
```

> NLS_CHARSET_ID returns the character set ID number corresponding to character set name string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the character set ID with `nls_charset_id` function.

Try this:

```
select
XMLType( BLOB_COLUMN,
         nls_charset_id('EE8ISO8859P2')
   ) as XML
from my_table;
```

Comment: Answered the same, 2 minutes before